# Not selecting passed in values for sub dropdowns

Tags: vue.js

I am running a Laravel applicaton with Vuejs and have a form that is laoded with vuejs and then validated with the backend. If I have validation that fails I am passing in the superintendent, homebuilder, and subdivision to the form component. When the form loads back up it will not automattically select the subdivision and superintendent if a homebuilder is selected. I am still getting the correct values for the passed in superintendent and subdivision. It is currently not populating the two dropdowns with their neccessary options.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-required">
          <label for="homebuilder" class="control-label">Homebuilder</label>
          <select class="form-control" required name="homebuilder" v-model="homebuilder" v-on:change="chooseHomebuilder()">
            <option :value="null">-- Select Homebuilder --</option>
            <option v-for="homebuilder in homebuilders" :value="homebuilder.id">{{homebuilder.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <template v-if="chosenHomebuilder">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group form-group-required">
                <label for="subdivision" class="control-label">Subdivision</label>
                <select class="form-control" required name="subdivision" v-model="subdivision">
                  <option :value="null">-- Select Subdivision --</option>
                  <option v-for="subdivision in chosenHomebuilder.subdivisions" :value="subdivision.id">{{subdivision.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group form-group-required">
                <label for="superintendent" class="control-label">Superintendent</label>
                <select class="form-control" required name="superintendent" v-model="superintendent">
                  <option :value="null">-- Select Superintendent --</option>
                  <option v-for="superintendent in chosenHomebuilder.superintendents" :value="superintendent.id">{{superintendent.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


props: ['oldHomebuilder', 'oldSuperintendent', 'oldSubdivision']
chosenHomebuilder: this.oldHomebuilder,
homebuilder: this.oldHomebuilder,
superintendent: this.oldSuperintendent,
subdivision: this.oldSubdivision,

chooseHomebuilder: function(){
    if(this.chosenHomebuilder) {
      _.map(this.chosenHomebuilder.phases,(obj) => {
        return obj.chosen = false;
      });
    }
    if( this.homebuilder ){
      var self = this;
      this.homebuilders.filter(function(obj){
        if( obj.id === self.homebuilder ){
          self.chosenHomebuilder = obj;
        }
      });
    }else{
      this.chosenHomebuilder = null;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VueJS 2.0, in order for your template to be reactive to the data you change, you need to encapsulate your data in the data object, and your methods in the methods object like so:

```
{
    data: () => {
        return {
            chosenHomebuilder: this.oldHomebuilder,
            homebuilder: this.oldHomebuilder,
            superintendent: this.oldSuperintendent,
            subdivision: this.oldSubdivision,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        chooseHomebuilder() {
            if (this.chosenHomebuilder) {
                _.map(this.chosenHomebuilder.phases, (obj) => {
                    return obj.chosen = false;
                });
            }
            if (this.homebuilder) {
                var self = this;
                this.homebuilders.filter(function(obj) {
                    if (obj.id === self.homebuilder) {
                        self.chosenHomebuilder = obj;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                this.chosenHomebuilder = null;
            }

        }
    }
}
```